# Pycharm (Django) stopping on a breakpoint only on the first request

Tags: django, breakpoints, pycharm

I'm debugging `Django` setting up breakpoints in *pycharm*.

I have multiple sequential request to the same resource coming from ajax and I can't predict the exact same order in which they will arrive

Pycharm seems to stop only on the first one, but from the console I can see that actually all the requestes happened and they were served.

My tough is that in a way there are multiple threads and pycharm stops only on the first one, not sure..

Under the Run/Debug configuration I've checked the option "single instance only" but it doesn't seems to help.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**
On lower left corner I found the "frames" box from where I can switch the current thread. I've switched thread and found the variable I was interested on.
[image]

This is kind of complicated for debugging..isn't there any option to run in single process/thread mode for debugging purposes?

Comment: The "Single Instance Only" option is to prevent multiple run/debug instances, this mean that run/debug configuration cannot be launched more than once. It's not single instances for "requests".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, solved

I had to add the option `--nothreading` to the `runserver` command (see the image below) in this way all the requests are `blocking` meaning django will serve them one after another in sequence

[image]